# CKEDITOR 4.3.2 IE11 Permission Denied

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

So I am writing a plugin for ckeditor (@mentions).

When you type some characters (example "@John") a drop down will appear of a list of Johns that the user can select . When the users selects the drop down they want, it needs to remove the the "@John" text and insert an element that was retrieved from the dropdown. The problem occurs when trying to insert text, remove some text and setting the currsor position.

**The Code**

```
var html = '<span>InsertedElement</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;';
// Create the Element to insert
var newElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(html, mentions.editor.document);
//Insert the element
mentions.editor.insertElement(newElement);
//Get a new bookmark
var tempBookMark = mentions.editor.getSelection().createBookmarks(true);
// get the data
var edata = mentions.editor.getData();
// set it with the exact same info so not changes (just for the test)
mentions.editor.setData(edata);
//set the bookmark
mentions.editor.getSelection().selectBookmarks(tempBookMark);
//focas on that position
mentions.editor.focus();
```

**The issue**

This works just fine on chrome however on IE11 after the text has been removed, when I try to access the mentions.editor.getSelection() I get "permission denied" error. I cannot set the bookmark and the focus is moved to the start of the ckeditor.

[Update]
A further test I performed narrowed down the issue. Commenting out the *mentions.editor.setData(edata);* line it stops erroring. If I use the setData function on the editor instance and then try to to run the GetSelection() on the Editor instance it errors (permission denied) in IE11 but works in Chrome. Its seems the setData function locks the editor in some way in IE11? I have simplified the code to allow it to be more easily replicated.

Comment: Without the full working sample it's very hard to help. But regarding the "permission denied" error itself, I know that it's thrown when you try to access element which document doesn't exist any more, so maybe you're caching something for too long.

Comment: The Full example uses a local service so hard to post the full script etc. I have simplified the code and provided a further test case that narrows down where the issue occurs. Hopefully this helps @Reinmar? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [`Editor#setData`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setData) is an asynchronous function. You cannot use selection right after setting data - you have to wait until everything is ready. Therefore `setData` accepts callback.

```
mentions.editor.setData( edata, function() {
    //set the bookmark
    mentions.editor.getSelection().selectBookmarks(tempBookMark);
    //focas on that position
    mentions.editor.focus();
} );
```